# Pandas date_range() for middle and end of month

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I can specify the date range of month ends using

```
import pandas as pd
monthend_range = pd.date_range(datetime.date(2017,12,10), datetime.date(2018,2,2), freq='BM')
```

Is there a straightforward way to include the middle of the month into the range above to form a middle-and-end-month index? Let's say that the logic we want is to use the successive month ends in the code above and find the business day that is right in the middle between the monthends. If that is not a business day, then try the following day and the following until we get a business day.

The expected output is

```
['2017-12-29', '2018-01-16', '2018-01-31']
```

This might seem a bit inconsistent as 2017-12-15 is a middle of the month that is within the date range. But the procedure is get the end of months, then interpolate between the ends. Unless of course there is a better approach to dealing with this question.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Sure. Let me count the days and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is create business day range for each value with omit first and select value in the middle, last use [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) for join togetehr:

```
a = [] 
for x in monthend_range[1:]:
    r = pd.date_range(x.to_period('m').to_timestamp(), x, freq='B')
    a.append(r[len(r)//2])
print (a)
[Timestamp('2018-01-16 00:00:00', freq='B')]

out = monthend_range.union(a)
print (out)           
DatetimeIndex(['2017-12-29', '2018-01-16', '2018-01-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```